# Blender Geonodes Fields 3.01 Get position of instance?

Tags: procedural, instances, geometry-nodes

My question is how do I capture the position data of an instance using fields?

I've tried following the advice in this thread as it has the same title as my question but it doesn't really answer the question. It seems more of a workaround for a specific use case example:
[Capturing position data of instances using fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247404/capturing-position-data-of-instances-using-fields)

I have drawn a parabolic curve between two empties, I would now like to draw another parabola between a specified distance along the curve, which I can then daisy chain to get several iterations depending on the length of the curve.

[image]

I think I don't understand how capture attribute works, as this is my current setup:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The `Position` node refers to the original geometry and not any generated geometry.  If you want the center of the object, use the `Bounding Box` node and take the average of the `min` and `max` vectors.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was to use the *Realize Instances* node and then get the position of the new geometry from the *Set Position* node and the *Position* node.

[image: shows the nodes used]